# How to submit an app rating without disclosing name

Tags: apps

With some apps relentlessly asking to be rated, I submitted a few. However, I noticed that in the reviews in the app, my name appears in the review.

Some reviews only have their submitter's name as "User". How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your name in Microsoft account to `User`! Many of the windows phone users created their Microsoft account just to start using the phone, they must have filled the Name field with anything, I guess they do not notice because they are not using the Microsoft account as their main account.